# Update a single column with data from another row in that column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a DB that has 4 columns, DOC_ID, DOC_CODE, ORIG_DOC_ID, and ITEM_ID. The DOC_CODE is either I or B, with each I DOC_ID having a corresponding B DOC_ID shown as ORIG_DOC_ID. Example:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|    DOC_ID       |    ORIG_DOC_ID    | DOC_CODE  |    ITEM_ID  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|     33456       |    44567          |     I     |     NULL    |
|     44567       |    NULL           |     B     |     254     |
|     45785       |    67584          |     I     |     NULL    |
|     67584       |    NULL           |     B     |     234     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to run an UPDATE script that takes the ITEM_IDs from DOC_IDs with DOC_CODE B, and inserts them into the ITEM_ID Column in the corresponding DOC_ID with DOC_CODE I. So the table, after the script, would look like:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|    DOC_ID       |    ORIG_DOC_ID    | DOC_CODE  |    ITEM_ID  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|     33456       |    44567          |     I     |     254     |
|     44567       |    NULL           |     B     |     254     |
|     45785       |    67584          |     I     |     234     |
|     67584       |    NULL           |     B     |     234     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any advice would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Yes I did! Sorry I thought I had accepted this answer and commented. Thank you very much for the help! :)

Comment: No problem, glad you got it working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
update TableOne   set item_id = xx.Item_id
from       
(       
select doc_id,item_id
from TableOne
where Doc_Code='B'
) xx where TableOne.Orig_doc_id=xx.doc_id
```

SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1a442/2